# How to evaluate the fuel consumption rate of an air conditioner in a vehicle?

Tags: aerodynamics

Using two cases studies: I. When the windows are wound up and air conditioner is turned on. II. When the windows are wound down and air conditioner is turned off.

Case studies are evaluated for driving in city and highway but more importantly how can the fuel consumption rate of the AC be measured so as to suggest when it is more economical to use it and reduce the effects of drag on the vehicle?

Comment: an average air conditioner takes between 0 and 15bhp.... but the load at any given instant is dependent on many factors...

Comment: It depends on the engine and vehicle. With big old US V-8 you can not see an mpg difference until the 2nd decimal place. I expect testing could find a difference with a modern 2 L.

Comment: Not the most accurate of methods. Do numerous driving runs under as similar conditions as possible - the more runs the better. Drive the vehicle several times with windows shut & no AC, then do likewise with the AC operating. Get the overall average under each driving condition & compare.